# Dynamically populate markup with XML data using javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm on a .NET 4.0 environment using jQuery and Visual Studio to write everything, but neither of these facts should matter that much except how to populate the XML data.

I'm starting out with this script which has a lot of markup in it. My task is to get the markup out of the script and to populate the the XML data into the markup in its proper place. I'm trying to keep the presentation and behavior layers as separate as possible by doing this.

```
function addIcons(IconType) {
    var li ="";
    var onclickMethod="";
    for (var item in hashObject) {
        var thumbNail = item.split("_");
        if (thumbNail[0] == IconType +"ThumbNail") {
            var imagePath = baseUrlThumbNailImages + hashObject[item];

            li = li + "<li  onclick=IconClick('" + IconType +"',"+ thumbNail[1] + ")><img src=\"" + imagePath + "\" alt=\"" + IconType + " shape\"></li>\n";
        }
    }
    $("#" + IconType + "ThumbNailShapes").append(li);
}
```

Here's example markup I want as final result:

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="IconClick('Item',1)">
    <img src="/images/image_1.png" alt="Item shape" />
  </li>
  <li onclick="IconClick('Item',2)">
    <img src="/images/image_2.png" alt="Item shape" />
  </li>
  <li onclick="IconClick('Item',3)">
    <img src="/images/image_3.png" alt="Item shape" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

While I know I need to take out the line of code that starts `li = li + ...`, I'm also not familiar enough with OOP to understand how to write a for loop to populate the markup.

So there's two factors that I am not sure how to code:

1. The blank markup - does the markup need variables to populate it or should javascript do this automatically?
2. The javascript - I don't know how to recode the javascript to find each list item and image tag to populate the various data.

Do I need the markup to be blank like this, where all the variable data is not there yet?

```
<ul id="IconThumbnailShapes">
  <li onclick="">
    <img src="" alt="shape" />
  </li>
  <li onclick="">
    <img src="" alt="shape" />
  </li>
  <li onclick="">
    <img src="" alt="shape" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

I appreciate the insight and help.

Comment: what have you tried?...there are lots of AJAX tutorials and examples on web of how to parse xml to html

Comment: Well, trying to grasp what these tutorials are saying, I really don't understand what to do. I'm still way too limited in my javascript knowledge to understand how to write this out properly. I know various bits and pieces of this and that but putting it all together doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: start with simple examples. Lots of demos with source code provided. then start matching those concepts to your data.

Comment: Right, I get what you're saying. I just don't even know where to start. What I understand about the javascript above is that there are three variables which need to populate into the markup in various places. But, how to get both the variable value and the incremental number value, all at once in various unordered lists, it just doesn't make sense what to do.

Comment: @micah: Watch these: http://yuiblog.com/crockford/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this.

Let's suppose we have a container DIV#foo where all this code has to reside.

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

We then do this:

```
$(function() {
   // DOM ready

   $('#foo').on('click', '#IconThumbnailShapes li', function() {
       // Do whatever you have to do with icon
       // Second argument there '#IconThu... li' means the event will be trigerred 
       // as soon as you add your icons, but they don't have to be there 
       // right now.
   });

   function addIcons(iconType) {
       var s = '<ul id="IconThumbnailShapes">'
       var l = '<li><img src="$SRC" alt="$ICON shape" /></li>'
       var data = [{...}, {...}, {...}];
       var len = data.length;

       var datum;

       for (var i = len; i; i--) {
          datum = data[len - i];
          s += l.replace('$SRC', datum.src).replace('$ICON', iconType);
       }

       s += '</ul>';

       $('#foo').html(s);       
   }

});
```

So, we do it like this, because we don't want to fire jQuery stuff in the for loop. That kills performance. Instead we set up a deferred even handler for click on the conainer DIV#foo, and we shove the whole bunch of markup into the container as a string.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I'm trying to separate the presentation layer (HTML markup) from the behavior layer (javascript). That's why I need to rewrite this code.

Comment: @micah: Okiedokie, let me rewrite it. :)

Comment: My hope is to have the markup already exist in the HTML file but to have the javascript identify and populate the incremental variable data of the XML into the right spots in the code. Is it not possible to have the unordered list and list items exist already? The code you provided is dynamically inserting all the variable data AND markup into the div.

Comment: @micah: That's just not efficient. It's better to just build markup than manipulate the DOM in a for loop. You can certainly have some HTML placeholder or an ajax loading spinner icon like the ones you find on http://ajaxload.info/. But it's better to use a client-side template, or a simple string with a few replace calls, and build the markup that way.

Comment: can use templates... but they result in parsing strings internally themselves

Comment: @charlietfl: Parsing strings is cheap. Especially if it's a tiny little string like the one OP needs. Manipulating DOM is expensive as hell. In this case, it probably won't make too much of a difference, but it does make a difference nevertheless.

Comment: @bvukelic This is where I really don't understand DOM manipulation and efficiency. I'm still getting used to JS and I guess I was thinking of it in terms of how I've written PHP in the WordPress environment where there would be echo statements that could populate the data. So I was thinking, why can't there be JS variables in the markup which pull the data in a similar fashion dynamically?

Comment: @bvukelic I totally agree... I write lots of string concatenation..  rarely use templates. Templates aren't really based on DOM manipulation since parsing is done outside the DOM though

Comment: @charlietfl: Oh, that's what you meant. Yeah, agreed again.

Comment: @micah: In JS, you don't manipulate the page as string. You manipulate it as DOM objects. (You could technically read the innerHTML of body element, and edit the contents as string, but that's not very nice.) So, since DOM is slow you don't want to fiddle with it too much. Instead, you build small pieces of markup using strings and stuff like `.replace()` (or use templates), and inject whole blocks in the DOM in one go.

Comment: @micah: DOM also takes care of inconsistencies in markup like whether there is a space there or newline here or attributes not being quoted, so all in all, it's a necessary evil. Here's a short intro to DOM here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/About_the_Document_Object_Model

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. No matter how long I've worked on the front end, the concept of DOM manipulation has always confused me. I have a lot to learn!

Comment: @micah: That's because DOM *is* a confusing beast. That's why there are things like jQuery, MooTools, and others. :)